# I want to accept bitcoin on my raspberry pi

Tags: bitcoind, merchants, ecommerce, raspberry-pi

I have a web server running on a raspberry pi and I want to accept bitcoins. I have very little disk space so I don't have room to install bitcoind. I don't trust any third party services to process my payments so that wont work. Is it possible to accept bitcoins with my setup?

Comment: Do you trust third party services to report your payments?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I would rather not but if I have to I will to get it working

Comment: Then you can use a service like blockchain.info to detect payments. Use a cold wallet to receive them.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Ok that works for me can you write a full answer explaining it completely?

Comment: When you say web server I'm assuming like a LAMP server that host websites. I'm aware that there are different types of servers but web server makes me think of a LAMP like server. That being said why don't you just use a bitcoin address from a wallet from another computer and put it on the website

Comment: @BenP.Dorsi-Todaro Yes it is a LAMP server. Your method won't work because I need to verify the identity of the person who transfers the money so I can be sure that they paid.

Comment: If you have sqlite on the server you can store multiple addresses in the database, create simple login system that assigns an address from the one table to each user who logins in.

Answer (score 1):

Any special situation for you to want your wallet IN your rapberry?
A wallet doesn't need to be in a physical machine, actually it can be in a sheet of paper (cold wallet). So if you don't need your server to do anything special with those coins you can just create a paper wallet, and if what you really want is to check if you receive coins, you only have to check from your raspberry your wallet's public key in blockchain to see how many coins has it received.

If you want to create a wallet, you can use `vanitygen`. Keep the public and private keys in a safe place and you are ready to go. The day you need to move those coins you will need to install bitcoin-qt wherever you want and import your private key to the default wallet created by bitcoin-qt. Once you've done that you can operate with your coins from that place.

Comment: I believe the asker wants to accept payments, which generally requires generating multiple addresses and detecting payments to them.

Comment: The answer serves that purpose too. If he uses `vanitygen` or any other key generator in his raspberry he can generate addresses dynamically and he doesn't need to have bitcoind running. Of course that method is risky in case his raspberry is compromised.

Comment: "and detect payments to them"

Comment: As I stated in my answer detecting payments is as simple as querying blockchain, he still doesn't need bitcoind.

Answer (score 0):

You would need an SPV wallet in order to receive bitcoins. The only one I know of that's SPV and runs on Raspberry Pi is this Pi-Wallet, which uses electrum servers to detect payments: http://www.pi-wallet.com/pages/free-stuff

Note that it uses the Armory offline wallet built for Raspberry Pi to actually generate addresses.